# Prevent entry of GemFire cache being accessed by more than one request

Tags: gemfire

I have an application using Springboot, Gemfire and MySQL. The Springboot application serves as a rest api. I want to "lock" the cache entry so that only one request sent to rest api can access certain entry in GemFire at a time. Others cannot do CRUD on that entry until the entry owner release the possession. I have two approaches as of now.

Approach 1 - Create a GemFire function, which performs a lock/unlock on the entry when invoked by rest api(at different time) using org.apache.geode.cache.Region.getDistributedLock.

Approach 2 - Create a region(eg. Lock) where an entry is created when an entry of target region(eg. Customer) is accessed for the fist time. When the 2nd request wants to access the same entry, the rest api checks the region Lock first. Rest api retrieves and returns the entry from region Customer if the key does not exist in region Lock. Otherwise, no entry will be returned. Once the first requester finishes, rest api removes the entry in region Lock.

I am wondering if there are any alternatives besides these two options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more space efficient solution, you could add a boolean field to the value to indicate if it was locked. You can then use region.replace(K,V,V) to efficiently set the "lock" on the entry as well. Although, this will leak your locking concerns into your business objects.